# how can I add current directory to ruby loadpath permanently

Tags: ruby

How can I add the '.' permanently to my ruby loadpath. I don't care about security issues, just make it permanently there across session is fine with me. And please also do not tell me to use require_relative or the kind. I have got tons of occurences of require. It's sticky to change them all at once. I just need the '.' to be in the path.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `RUBYLIB` environment variable for your shell to include the current path `.`. If you want multiple paths to search from, you can separate each path with `:`.

```sh
export RUBYLIB=.
```

Test:

```sh
$ RUBYLIB='.' ruby -e "p $:"
```

UPDATE: Put the environment variable settings in your shell's initialization script so that it gets set every time you launch your shell.

Comment: Won't this only be accessible from the current instance of the shell and child processes? That is, once the shell exits or if you start ruby from a different shell, this won't affect it.

Comment: +1 @jpmc26. The variable will have to be set in ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile to make it static. And, that will be a non-standard behavior which will surely come back to bite the OP in the future.

Comment: BTW, one more follow up. What's the different between RUBYLIB and $LODA_PATH(which is shorthanded as $: ). Which one shall I change

Comment: @Daniel Ruby read `RUBYLIB` environment variable and some built-in arrays/variables to get the default `$LOAD_PATH`. So you can change `RUBYLIB` to add search path before ruby starts. And `$LOAD_PATH` is a Ruby variable, you can manipulate it after ruby starts, using Ruby syntax.

Comment: @ArieShaw Thanks that's quite helpful!

Answer (score 0):

`$:.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)`

Should add the directory of the file you place the snippet on.

If you want the directory where you are currently working on (where you call the file from) you can do the following:

`$:.unshift Dir.getwd`