# Permanently add a directory to Ruby $LOAD_PATH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, awesomeprint

I'd like the option to use [awesome_print](https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print) in every IRB console or Rails console.

The IRB console is pretty much working satisfactorily right now. If I run `irb`, I can type `require 'awesome_print'` and it works.

The Rails console isn't as easy. `require 'awesome_print'` doesn't work. I apparently have to do this:

`> $LOAD_PATH << '~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.8/gems/awesome_print-1.7.0/lib'`

After that, `require 'awesome_print'` works fine.

But I definitely don't want to have to type `$LOAD_PATH << '~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.8/gems/awesome_print-1.7.0/lib'` and then `require 'awesome_print'` every single time I open a Rails console just to be able to use `awesome_print`. That seems ridiculous.

So, how can I permanently add a path to Ruby's `$LOAD_PATH`?

Note: I *don't* want to add `awesome_print` to the `Gemfile` of any particular project. I want `awesome_print` to be available to *all* my Ruby/Rails projects.

Comment: take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952290/how-can-i-add-current-directory-to-ruby-loadpath-permanently

Comment: @ZachTuttle That didn't seem to do it for me, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use a a `~/.irbrc` file and do:

```
require 'awesome_print'
```

Now, open up another IRB prompt:

```
irb(main):003:0> ap hash
{
    "a" => "b"
}
```

Edit:  this isn't working in rails, seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/374).

Comment: it will depend on your version of ruby that you'r invoking `irb` with.  if your gem isn't installed for that version of ruby, it will fail.  You can always check it with `ruby ~/.irbrc` to see if you get any warnings.  The rails issue is known.

Comment: Sorry, it does in fact work for me in IRB. I don't know why it didn't work initially but now it does.

Comment: The issue you linked to seems to be an issue of Rails ignoring `~/.irbrc`. I don't have that problem. Rails picks up `~/.irbrc` fine, it just says `cannot load such file -- awesome_print`, presumably because it's lacking the right path in `$LOAD_PATH`.

Comment: interesting, i couldn't get it to pick up my irbrc file.  Same version of ruby in your rails app?  you could `puts ruby -v` at the top of your ~/.irbrc file to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

puts the following to the `.irbrc`:

```
to_load = %w[
  awesome_print
  coderay
  hirb
  pry
  pry-doc
  pry-remote
  pry-theme
  slop
  yard
].join('|')

regexp = Regexp.new( "(#{to_load})" )

Gem.path.each do |path|
  Dir.new("#{path}/gems").each do |gem_path|
    next if %w[ . .. ].any?{ |d| gem_path == d }

    new_el = "#{path}/gems/#{gem_path}/lib"
    $LOAD_PATH << new_el if new_el =~ regexp
  end
end
```